# Using a Workbook, how to transform all the pivot tables in a normal range preserving values and format of the original pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, file, pivot, range

How to develope a code in vba to transform all pivot tables in a file into a normal range but keeping the values and formatting of these pivot tables.

The code below it doesn't works.

```
Sub ConvertPivotTablesToRanges()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            Set rng = pt.TableRange1
            rng.Copy
            rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            pt.TableRange1.ClearContents
            pt.TableRange1.MergeCells = False
        Next pt
    Next ws
End Sub
```